# I am trying to do here is to call a class's constructor. But it is giving me an error. It is saying: missing1 requiered positional argument

Tags: python-3.x, linux, sqlite, api, orm

```
class Sensor(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    temperature = db.Column(db.Float())
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime)

    def __init__(self, temperature, date=None):
        self.temperature = temperature
        if date is None:
            date = datetime.utcnow()
        self.date = date

class SensorSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = Sensor
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This snippet of code doesn't tell us much about the problem you are having.

Answer (score 0):

`from flask_restful import Resource
from flask import request, jsonify
from app import app, api, db, auth, users
from sensor import Sensor, SensorSchema

schema = SensorSchema()

@auth.get_password
def get_pw(username):
    if username in users:
        return users.get(username)
    return None

class Index(Resource):
    decorators = [auth.login_required]

```
def get(self):
    return "Hello, %s!" % auth.username()
```

class TemperatureList(Resource):
    decorators = [auth.login_required]

```
def get(self):
    allTemperatures = Sensor.query.all()
    result = schema.dump(allTemperatures, many=True).data
    return result

def post(self):
    args = request.get_json()
    sensor_read = Sensor(args["temperature"])
    sensor_read1 = Sensor(args["login"])
    db.session.add(sensor_read, sensor read1)
    return "Temperature added", 200
```

class Temperature(Resource):
    decorators = [auth.login_required]

```
def get(self, id):
    temperature = Sensor.query.get(id)
    result = schema.dump(temperature).data
    return result
```

api.add_resource(Index, "/api/v1.0", endpoint="index")
api.add_resource(TemperatureList, "/api/v1.0/temperature", endpoint="temperatures")
api.add_resource(
    Temperature, "/api/v1.0/temperature/", endpoint="temperature"
)

if **name** == "**main**":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
`